# Deno + Vite + Sass failed to load

Tags: sass, vite, deno

I'm trying to use Sass with Deno + Vite (see templates [create-vite-extra](https://github.com/bluwy/create-vite-extra)).

I added `import "npm:sass@^1.57.0"` to `vite.config.mjs`. The package is available in `node_modules`.

It seems Vite fails to resolve the path to sass, but given the callstack I'm not sure if this is a bug in Vite or Deno.

```
14:03:05 [vite] Internal server error: Preprocessor dependency "sass" failed to load:
Empty filepath.
  Plugin: vite:css
  File: C:/project/src/foo.scss
      at pathDirname (deno:ext/node/02_require.js:50:13)
      at new Module (deno:ext/node/02_require.js:255:17)
      at Function.Module._resolveFilename (deno:ext/node/02_require.js:553:30)
      at Function.resolve (deno:ext/node/02_require.js:811:21)
      at requireResolveFromRootWithFallback (file:///C:/project/node_modules/.deno/vite@4.0.2/node_modules/vite/dist/node/chunks/dep-6305614c.js:12238:23)        
      at loadPreprocessor (file:///C:/project/node_modules/.deno/vite@4.0.2/node_modules/vite/dist/node/chunks/dep-6305614c.js:38038:26)
      at scss (file:///C:/project/node_modules/.deno/vite@4.0.2/node_modules/vite/dist/node/chunks/dep-6305614c.js:38083:20)
      at compileCSS (file:///C:/project/node_modules/.deno/vite@4.0.2/node_modules/vite/dist/node/chunks/dep-6305614c.js:37603:40)
      at async TransformContext.transform (file:///C:/project/node_modules/.deno/vite@4.0.2/node_modules/vite/dist/node/chunks/dep-6305614c.js:37156:56)
      at async Object.transform (file:///C:/project/node_modules/.deno/vite@4.0.2/node_modules/vite/dist/node/chunks/dep-6305614c.js:42626:30)
      at async loadAndTransform (file:///C:/project/node_modules/.deno/vite@4.0.2/node_modules/vite/dist/node/chunks/dep-6305614c.js:40434:29)
      at loadPreprocessor (file:///C:/project/node_modules/.deno/vite@4.0.2/node_modules/vite/dist/node/chunks/dep-6305614c.js:38046:29)
      at scss (file:///C:/project/node_modules/.deno/vite@4.0.2/node_modules/vite/dist/node/chunks/dep-6305614c.js:38083:20)
      at compileCSS (file:///C:/project/node_modules/.deno/vite@4.0.2/node_modules/vite/dist/node/chunks/dep-6305614c.js:37603:40)
      at async TransformContext.transform (file:///C:/project/node_modules/.deno/vite@4.0.2/node_modules/vite/dist/node/chunks/dep-6305614c.js:37156:56)
      at async Object.transform (file:///C:/project/node_modules/.deno/vite@4.0.2/node_modules/vite/dist/node/chunks/dep-6305614c.js:42626:30)
      at async loadAndTransform (file:///C:/project/node_modules/.deno/vite@4.0.2/node_modules/vite/dist/node/chunks/dep-6305614c.js:40434:29)
```

**Update**

I retested with [Deno version v1.31.1](https://github.com/denoland/deno/releases/tag/v1.31.1) but unfortunately still getting the same error.

Comment: Did u figure it out urself?

Comment: @webprogrammer Unfortunately no. I stopped experimenting with deno for now.